# How to create an array from a text file with php?

Tags: php

I have a text file like this:

```
Host: x-sgdo43.serverip.co
Username: mywebsite.com-user
Password: pass
Port: 443
Info: Date Expired : 26-October-2016
```

And I want to create an array from that text file so each key and value should look like this:

```
Host => x-sgdo43.serverip.co
Username => mywebsite.com-user
Password => pass
Port => 443
Info => Date Expired : 26-October-2016
```

What I have tried so far is using:

```
parse_ini_string(str_replace(': ', '=', file_get_contents('myfile.txt')));
```

But I always get this error:

> Warning: syntax error, unexpected '=' in Unknown on line 5

Comment: You can use [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) with `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` and take it from there.

Comment: That makes perfect sense as the 5th line has 2 `: `'s.

Comment: `file()` function what you wanted:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: If I use `file` then the value will contain the entire line like this `Host: x-sgdo43.serverip.co` instead of `x-sgdo43.serverip.co` I don't want the `Host: ` part

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match` (regex) could be a solution :

```
parse_ini_string(
    preg_replace(
        '/^([^:]+): (.+)$/m',
        '$1 = $2',
        file_get_contents('myfile.txt')
    )
);
```

The `preg_match` here replaces only the first ": " occurence of each line by "=".

[Live REGEX-example](https://regex101.com/r/5MbYiz/5)

Inspired by [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/266732/matching-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-line-with-regex)

Comment: Cool, but I have to change `=>` to `=` or there's gonna be an extra `>` in each value. Anyway what does `mU` do in that code ?

Comment: m: multiline (^ and $ represents the beginning and end of the line) and U: Ungreedy (avoid the first match to cover everything)

Comment: @hillz: I edited my answer, the U flag is not necessary.

Comment: After I try removing the `U` flag, it doesn't show anything so the `U` flag is definitely needed :)

Comment: I did change `/(^...` to `/^(...` while removing the `U` flag. Most live version shows a good replace: https://regex101.com/r/5MbYiz/6

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Anant's answer here is my code,

```
function file_to_arr($file)
{
$myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
     $exploded_data = explode(": ",fgets($myfile));
     if(in_array("Info",$exploded_data))
    $text[$exploded_data[0]] = $exploded_data[1].' : '.$exploded_data[2];
    else
     $text[$exploded_data[0]] = $exploded_data[1];
}
fclose($myfile);
return $text;
}

print_r(file_to_arr('tt.txt'));

Array ( [Host] => x-sgdo43.serverip.co [Username] => mywebsite.com-user [Password] => pass [Port] => 443 [Info] => Date Expired : 26-October-2016 )
```